# How to show wavy underline(Error Squiggles) when word is wrong in vs code extension development

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

When developing an extension that has syntax checking how to show the wavy underline when word typed is wrong.

As of now, my extension shows only color change when the correct word is entered. But I want to underline the error.

Ex:- If frm is entered then it should underline as 'from' is the valid keyword.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this??

Comment: @ShahzadAkram No. If you have any solution please share it.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#provide-diagnostics

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [vscode-extension-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples), there are so many useful samples as a guide. I was also struggling with this type of issue and I found [code-actions-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/code-actions-sample) solved the problem in my case.